# Most efficient way to compute managed value

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, scalability

I'm far from being a pandas expert. I'm a regular dev guy.

I would like to calculate a managed value.
I've got a df which is the market prices per day (with date as index) and and dfTrend which is 0 and 1 with the same index.

I want to send both those dataframe to a function and get a managed value, meaning when the trend is zero, I want the managed value to remain flat and when the trend is one, i want the value to increase and follow the market prices.

for example:[image]

My code works fine but it's very slow:

```
def getManagedValue(df, dfTrend):
    dfReturn = df.pct_change(1)
    dfManaged = df

    for col in df:
        for i in range(1, len(df[col])):
            dfManaged[col][0] = df[col][0]
            if dfTrend[col][i] == 1:
                dfManaged[col][i] = dfManaged[col][i-1] * (1 + dfReturn[col][i])
            else:
                dfManaged[col][i] = dfManaged[col][i-1]
    return dfManaged
```

Do anyone know how I can optimise this so that it runs faster ? the iteration of all cells of all columns is definitely the problem here.

I'm thinking of running this with cython, but I do believe i'm not allowed to use pandas with cython, only numpy's array...

Anyone has a suggestion ?

Cheers,
Julien

Answer (score 1):

Pandas' speed and power comes from operating on whole arrays rather than iterating over individual rows and cells.  If I follow the logic in your original example correctly, you can use `np.where` to do this faster:

```
dfManaged = np.where(dfTrend == 1, df.shift(1) * (1 + df.pct_change(1)), df.shift(1))
```

- [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy.where)
  lets you specify some condition (in this case, where `dfTrend == 1`)
  and assign values from one dataframe if that condition is true
  (`df.shift(1) * (1 + df.pct_change(1))`) and another if that
  condition is false (`df.shift(1)`).
- [`df.shift(1)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)
  moves all the values in `df` down one row, like `dfManaged[col][i-1]`
  but without having to iterate.
- Note that this performs the operation across the whole dataframe at once, rather than one row and column at a time.  That should speed it up.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what i'm looking. unfortunetaly, the df.shift(1) if Trend == 0 is still increasing when i want it to plateau. I can't figure out why. (i've tried to replace it with np.nan, and this work)

Comment: Sorry, is the problem with the code in your question / my answer, or with dfTrend itself?

Comment: In your answer, df.shift(1) does not keep the managed value to the same value while dfTrend =0.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean.  What behavior are you expecting and what is happening that you don't want?

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather you use the derivative (`df.pct_change(1)`) to reconstruct your curve. When the trend is `1`, you want to use this derivative, when it's `0` the derivative should be 0.

It's a little tricky to do this efficiently. One attempt would be to (i) use the `dfTrend` to modify the derivative and (ii) recalculate the `managed` as the cumulative sum of the derivative. You might experience some floating point errors here though -- I'm not sure.

```
# step 1
deriv = 1 + df.pct_change(1)
deriv[dfTrend == 0] = 0 
# step 2
managed = np.cumsum(deriv)
# optional -- remove potential floating point errors where possible
managed[dfTrend == 1] = df[dfTrend == 1]
```

Comment: Thanks, I found a pretty effective solution (see below), but I will try that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. I found the solution myself finally.

With a dataframe of [2696 rows x 305 columns],
It takes about 5 minutes to process it with pandas dataframe (using the code in the question).

I used numpy arrays and went down to 2.30 minutes.

And finally, I cythonized everything and went down to 2.5 seconds, which is definitely good enough.

Cheers,
Julien